# How to retrieve specific information from a column and show its number of occurrences

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a column which contains dates. I want to search this column and find the total entries for each month, and summarize the sum in a nice display. Example:

[image: Pic of Data Column]

I want to display the number of times 'Disposition Verification Dates' occur in each month and summarize ("count") them in a format which follows:

[image: Pic of Summary table]

I want to make several rows with the same concept in the same table for my other columns.

How do I do this? (PivotTables, VBA, IF statements?)

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: Do you want the Pivot Table, VBA, or Cell Formula (If Statement) Answer?

Comment: Remember to upvote or accept any answers that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a helper column which you can hide.  See the formula in cell C1.

For the January column I used the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$7, 1)
```

February is:

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$7, 2)
```

and so on.  You can also use the YEAR function and convert the countif into a COUNTIFS function based on the other year helper column.

[image]

Comment: You can also use the helper column in a possible pivot table *(since OP asked about pivot tables)* and change the formula in column c to `=TEXT(A2,"mmm")`. Or you can use the `=TEXT(A2,"mmm")` formula, and change the formula in F2 to `=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$7,F$1)` and drag it right over, so you don't have to edit the month count each time :)

Comment: I'm trying to use this but my MONTH() formula returns the format of 01-Jan-00 in column C instead of the integer 1. ( I would upvote your comments and help, but don't have enough rep pts)

Comment: Format the column as a number or something other than a date.

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious as to how this would be done in Pivot Tables

Answer (score 1):

No VBA needed. No helper column needed. No Pivot Table needed.

In addition to Yaegz provided, and my comments, you can use an array formula.

Assuming your data is column A and you type `Jan Feb Mar ... Dec` into cells `B1:N1`, you can enter the following formula in cell `B2`.

```
=COUNT(IF(TEXT($A$2:$A$13,"mmm")=B$1,$A$2:$A$13))
```

Then press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** (to make it work as an array) and you will have your summary done.

Comment: I will try this, and I would upvote your help but I don't have enough points.

Comment: you may have the points now. I just upvoted your question and you answered the question, so you now have 13 rep :)